# Efficiently backing up a folder with thousands of files/folders when only structure has changed

Tags: backup, sync

I have a folder which is backed up weekly to an external drive, approximately 150GB. There are approximately 36,000 music files. I've changed the folder structure drastically so that nearly half those files are in a different path. The sync program I use (Syncback) has produced a sync summary before the sync starts, telling me it will delete all the "missing" files from the external drive and then recopy them using the new folder structure. This will take most of the night with a slow USB connection.

Is there a program out there for Windows or Unix which can tell if a file has been moved and simply move  the destination file to the new location?

Comment: while a program to do this is entirely possible, this really defeats the purpose of a sync program.  These programs dont generate hashes of files and compare them, there isnt much of a need.  I doubt you will find a program that does this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is an open-source program called Unison that does exactly what you're describing: http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/ . It remembers a hash value for every file you're synchronizing. If a file moves, Unison can tell it's the same file, because it still has the same hash value. This may be a little time-consuming if it has to recalculate hashes on a large number of files, but probably less time-consuming than transmitting all the files over a slow connection. I've been using Unison for years now, and it's great. It runs on Windows and Unix.

Comment: Superb answer - this is extraordinarily fast.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [Bvckup 2](https://www.bvckup2.com) and it supports this. In fact, a "rename and move detection" is now pretty much a standard feature in all backup and filesync programs. I think SyncBack used to have an option for this as well, it was just off by default.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to run this on multiple OSes - this one is Windows only.

Answer (score -1):

The rsync program performs the same function, and it's a standard Linux utility.  There are a ton of options, but mostly you'll probably want -a (to keep permissions) and -P (to show progress.  There is also a -e ssh to transport data over an ssh connection.